# running app at heroku for the first time and got An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deploy a rails app for the first time in heroku but I got this kind of error

```
2017-01-06T10:26:15.630113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-brook-61028.herokuapp.com request_id=bdcee548-bb75-4ac0-a3fe-96bc16adaf32 fwd="112.198.103.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-06T10:26:17.045896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-brook-61028.herokuapp.com request_id=37217afd-7781-4f64-8ba3-fc2ad724a4d0 fwd="112.198.103.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

trying to visit the app and it display this message

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

This is the log result using the command heroku logs --tails

```
2017-01-06T11:29:39.413191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-brook-61028.herokuapp.com request_id=b47de71b-b562-4afd-8625-7082098f25f9 fwd="112.198.73.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-06T11:29:41.018749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-brook-61028.herokuapp.com request_id=f408aa4e-2bab-4a48-9404-56b47ed5e1a9 fwd="112.198.73.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-06T11:58:05.415446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-brook-61028.herokuapp.com request_id=0cf9d492-8e32-49b7-8166-6e983d3442d7 fwd="112.198.73.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

The application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MySecondApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

The production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "my_second_app_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end`
```

database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

please help me on this.

Comment: Can you post the result of this command: `heroku logs -t`? Run this in your terminal.

Comment: Also have you run the migrations in heroku? Most of the times its because of pending db creation and migrations.

Comment: @sahil, I already added logs in the question

Comment: Have you run the migrations?

Comment: If you can also post `application.rb, production.rb, database.yml` by masking the passwords it will be helpful or you can also checkout [my sample app's](https://github.com/sahil290791/discussions_app/tree/heroku) configuration which I have hosted on Heroku?

Comment: I updated it...

Comment: basically I am following here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#deploy-the-app, using ruby 2.4.0 and rails 5.0.1

Comment: Are you using sqlite or pg in production environment? Can you also post your Gemfile?

Comment: There are many unanswered questions as your error logs does not help at all. First which DB are you using in local and production(**Are both db's same or diff**, if diff DB's then how are you doing bundle install as for using different DB's in local and production requires bundle install to be done without production), what about `assets`, Is the app setup properly in Heroku (like all the **environment variables**)?,  have you added all the gems needed in Gemfile? Have you created the DB and run the migrations. It is difficult to pinpoint the error without knowing the above details for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [SQLite on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)... to fix that add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile in the `:production` group.

Ideally you should use the same db locally and in production, so I would install postgres locally...